# Is there way to inherit Fragment(@LayoutRes contentLayoutId: Int) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I wanted to make custom fragment class

abstract class MyBaseFragment:Fragment()

but when I inherit it I get error for too many argument

class ExampleFragment:MyBaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_example)

Is there way to inherit (@LayoutRes contentLayoutId: Int) instead of ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code

```
abstract class MyBaseFragment : Fragment {
    constructor() : super()
    constructor(@LayoutRes res: Int) : super(res)
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, I also use this